# Hartshorne (Chapter 2, 4.8), why isn't a open immersion written to be a proper morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

(I currently possess only the Japanese Edition of Hartshorne's book. Therefore, I kindly request that any answers provided do not rely on page numbers (of the English Edition) for reference. Thank you.)

In Corollary 4.8 in Chapter 2 of the book, it is stated that only closed immersions (and not open immersions) are considered proper. However, I believe the open immersions are proper under the assumption of the corollary. The following is the proof I wrote.

> This corollary assumes that all schemes are noetherian. Since $X$ is noetherian, an open immersion $f: X \to Y$ should also be quasi-compact. Thus $f$ is of finite type, by Exercise 3.13.$\require{AMScd}$
>
> \begin{CD}
>         \mathrm{Spec}\ K                       @>>>                        B \\
> @V{\text{$i$}}VV                                           @VV{\text{$f$}}V \\
>         \mathrm{Spec}\ R                    @>{\text{$\phi$}}>>                 D
> \end{CD}
>
> Now we can apply valuative criterion (Theorem 4.7). $f$ is a open immersion, so $f$ is a [split mono](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+monomorphism) and there is $g : Y \to X$ such that $gf = 1_X$. Then $g\phi : T \to X$ is the only morphism that remains the diagram above commutative. (The commutativity is evident. The uniqueness is followed by the fact that $f$ is separated or the fact that $f$ is a mono in the meaning of category theory.) By the criterion, it follows that $f$ is proper. $\blacksquare$

Is the proof above is wrong? Or was the fact that open immersions are proper under the assumption accidentally not written in the corollary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is wrong: open immersions are not in general split monos. For instance, over a field $k$, the open immersion of $\Bbb A^1\to\Bbb P^1$ as $D(t_1)$ cannot be split, because every map from $\Bbb P^1$ to $\Bbb A^1$ has image a point.

(Another reason this is wrong because a proper map is defined to be universally closed, and in particular closed. So an open immersion which does not have closed image can't be proper.)